# dll files not found. Miktex based error? How can I solve it?

Tags: miktex, texstudio

I’m working on a computer without admin rights and wanted to use Texstudio. Miktex was reinstalled (maybe 2/3 weeks ago) and seems to be working with Texworks.
I wanted to use Texstudio and tried – got the portable version and start it but got lots of error messages. Then got the installation version of Texstudio and I'm still getting the exact same error messages. Think this is due to Texstudio not finding the Miktex path. I have tried to fix that, but even then I’m getting the error messages. I’m somewhat at the end with my knowledge of how to fix this. Maybe someone has some more insight and can help me fix it?

Error messages contain the System error for latex.exe and kpsewhich.exe that some *.dll-files are missing.
[image: Error Messages]

Comment: obviously latex is found but then it doesn't find the needed dll. Check if you have more than one tex system.

Comment: Hi @UlrikeFischer thanks for your reply. I'm not aware that there is any other tex system installed. I saw the IT guy deinstall the old Miktex and install Miktex. There might be a hidden tex system (doubt it) but would there be a way to check that? I tried to give texstudio the correct path (of miktex) without any success....

Comment: run in a command line `where latex` and then check the content of the folder that reports.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the console reports the latex location: "C:\Program Files\MiKTex\miktex\bin\x64\latex.exe" - which is/was the expected location. But if I have a search (in "C:\Program Files\MiKTex\miktex\bin\x64\") for the MikTeX230400-web2c.dll file I can't find it...